# How can I generate documentation without writing any docstrings?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I generate documentation without writing a single line of docstring? I simply want to have an API reference page.

Because as I think, if there are type annotations in functions, then we don't need docstrings to describe them.

For example, one of my source code functions:

```py
def sort_files_by_time(self, files: List[str], reverse: bool = False):
    files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=reverse)
    return files
```

I expect it to generate API docs in HTML format. Like what I see in vscode function hint.

Comment: What's missing when you generate the HTML now?  Shouldn't using the `autodoc` plugin with `sphinx` be sufficient?

Comment: Sphinx has an `undoc-members` option:  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-option-automodule-undoc-members